# How to show the current execution progress of the Test Method on command line (MSTest Project )

Tags: mstest

I have developed an MS Test project for writing unit tests. In a test method which runs for long time, I want to print the current status to the standard output. I tried Console.Writeline(), TestContext.Writeline(), Trace.Writeline() functions but the statements are printed after completion of test method and not during the execution of test method. What is the solution for printing statements during execution of a test method?

I used Debug.WriteLine, Trace.WriteLine, Console.WriteLine, TextContext.WriteLine. But not able to get the messages on commandline. It displays after complete execution of the test method.
Some one told me "Trace.WriteLineAsync()" will work, but getting error when I am trying to add this on my MS Test Project. Please any one help me.
Thank You